# Why does Chinese Remainder Theorem imply that respective multiplicative inverse groups are isomorphic?

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem, ring-isomorphism

I came across this result: $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n_2\mathbb{Z}$ implies that $\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times} \cong \left(\mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times} \times \left(\mathbb{Z}/n_2\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}$

where $\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}$ denotes the multiplicative inverse group of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

So, I've been thinking that since the Chinese Remainder Theorem is about a ring isomorphism, namely $\phi : \alpha[n] \mapsto (\alpha[n_1],\alpha[n_2])$, I was thinking that $\phi(\alpha[n] \beta[n]) = \phi(\alpha[n])\phi(\beta[n])$ has to do something about the above result.

Here, $\alpha[n],\beta[n]$ denote some classes in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Many thanks in advance.

PS: $n_1, n_2$ are relatively prime and $n=n_1 n_2$

Comment: **Duplicate** of [Structure of a group of units of a ring composed of the direct product of two subrings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554249/structure-of-a-group-of-units-of-a-ring-composed-of-the-direct-product-of-two-su)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, every ring isomorphism $R\cong S$ induces a group isomorphism $U(R)\cong U(S)$. Here I write $U(R)=R^{\times}$ for the group of units of $R$. Secondly $U(S_1\times S_2)\cong U(S_1)\times U(S_2)$, see here:

[Structure of a group of units of a ring composed of the direct product of two subrings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554249/structure-of-a-group-of-units-of-a-ring-composed-of-the-direct-product-of-two-su)

Now apply this to $R=\Bbb Z/n$, $S_1=\Bbb Z/n_1$, $S_2=\Bbb Z/n_2$. By the CRT we have $R\cong S_1\times S_2$ for coprime integers $n_1$ and $n_2$. Hence
$$
U(n)\cong U(n_1)\times U(n_2),
$$
with $U(n)=(\Bbb Z/n)^{\times}$.